# interactiv multiangles (zoom+pan) video player

Tags: html, flash, video

i m looking for a multi angles video player for my swimming teen  team for analyse purpose.

i would like to make with videos like this one:

http://dg5rg8rin78k3.cloudfront.net/AUDIx4/AUDIx4_1080p-4mbps-25is-high-v2.mp4

a html5 video player like this:

https://www.current.fr/obs/plyr/unit/player/OmniPlayer.html?config_flash=https://www.current.fr/obs/plyr/unit/settings/audi/settings-flash.xml&config=https://www.current.fr/obs/plyr/unit/settings/audi/settings.xml

this videoplayer can be installed on pc ( web it s not important) and it can play videos like this above.

it will be great if you can give me some tips!

best regards

jerom

Answer (score 0):

** *Sorry, just re-read the question again and looked at the linked player. The sample below will create a mosaic, but not the interactivity you were looking for. There are probably commercial apps to do that on a PC, or you could run a web app locally with a server on the PC and display content from your local machine.* **

if you want to have the four videos synchronized then rather than using a player to play each individually you would want to create a single output video with a mosaic with the four input videos.

you can use something like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to do that, and then play the result back in any player that supports the selected video format (Windows Media Player, iTunes, VLC etc)

The example below will take four input videos and arrange them on a 640x480 canvas (depending on the quality/size of your source you can scale them up appropriately).

```
ffmpeg
    -i video1.mp3 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp3 -i video4.mp3
    -filter_complex "
      nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
      [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
      [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
      [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
      [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
      [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
      [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
      [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
      [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
    "
    -c:v libx264 videoMosaic.mp4
```